# Uncompressing a .gz string in C?

Tags: c, string, gzip, compression

I need to uncompress a .gz file (like stuff.txt.gz) that is currently stored in an arbitrarily long string. I've looked quite a bit at zip libraries but nothing has a straight answer.

popen is not acceptable, I need everything to be in my program. Also, this is Windows.

Can I have some help?

Comment: Have you heard of zlib ? http://www.gzip.org/zlib/manual.html

Comment: More specifically: http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq20

Comment: Have you tried to search for something yourself? Google is pretty useful for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [gzunpack](https://code.google.com/p/freecodecollection/wiki/gzunpack) library.

### Usage

```
#include "gzunpack.h"

...

    // read .GZ file header

    FILE *packedFileHandle = fopen("test1.gz", "rb");

    GzFileHeader *gzFileHeader = gzUnpackHeader(packedFileHandle);

    printf("Header:\n");
    printf("compressionMethod = %d\n", gzFileHeader->compressionMethod);
    printf("originalFileName = '%s'\n", gzFileHeader->originalFileName);
    printf("fileComment = '%s'\n", gzFileHeader->fileComment);

    // unpack .GZ file

    fseek(packedFileHandle, 0, SEEK_SET); // rewind

    FILE *unpackedFileHandle = fopen(gzFileHeader->originalFileName, "wb");

    gzUnpackFile(packedFileHandle, unpackedFileHandle);

    // free resources

    fclose(unpackedFileHandle);
    fclose(packedFileHandle);

    gzFreeHeader(gzFileHeader);
```